# FTPS. How to upload to a Home Folder only?

Tags: server, 20.04, ftp, vsftpd, filezilla

**Ubuntu 20.04, server.**

Wanted to configure the FTPS following instructions:
https://devanswers.co/install-ftp-server-vsftpd-ubuntu-20-04/

Did all actions and got error with FileZilla: `Response: 500 OOPS: cannot change directory:/var/www`

The problem is I did the **Step 4, method #1** firstly:

```
sudo usermod -d /var/www ftpuser
sudo chown ftpuser:ftpuser /var/www/html
```

After that I did **Step 4, method #2**

```
sudo mkdir /home/ftpuser/ftp
sudo chown nobody:nogroup /home/ftpuser/ftp

sudo chmod a-w /home/ftpuser/ftp
sudo mkdir /home/ftpuser/ftp/files
sudo chown ftpuser:ftpuser /home/ftpuser/ftp/files
```

Only **1** method should be done. This is my mistake. I'm quite new with Ubuntu server, my apologies for stupid questions.
How to upload to a Home Folder only? (Method #2)
The problem is 2 lines I did before, as I understand:

```
sudo usermod -d /var/www ftpuser
sudo chown ftpuser:ftpuser /var/www/html
```

Comment: @steeldriver thank you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the home directory back and reverse the first two lines with:

```
sudo usermod -d /home/ftpuser ftpuser
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www
```

usermod -d sets the home folder for a user.

When configuring vsftpd you may also need to edit the /etc/vsftpd.conf file.

Change the line:

```
local_root=/fake/path
```

To:

```
local_root=/home/$USER/ftp/files
```

This should change the root directory to the path created in your example.